# Jetty upgrade from 8.1.x to 9.4.x - HttpExchange class not found

Tags: java, migration, jetty

I am trying to upgrade the jetty version from 8.1.13 to 9.4.43.
Since this is a major upgrade, HttpExchange class has been changed a lot. Many methods of HttpExchange are deprecated and I am finding it difficult to find an alternative for these methods.

```
  HttpExchange exchange = new HttpExchange() {
            protected void onRequestCommitted() throws IOException {
            }

            protected void onRequestComplete() throws IOException {
            }

            protected void onResponseComplete() throws IOException {
            }

            protected void onResponseContent(Buffer content) throws IOException {
                content.writeTo(out);
            }

            protected void onResponseHeaderComplete() throws IOException {
            }

            protected void onResponseStatus(Buffer version, int status, Buffer reason) throws IOException {
            }

            protected void onResponseHeader(Buffer name, Buffer value) throws IOException {
                
            }

            protected void onConnectionFailed(Throwable ex) {
                onException(ex);
            }

            protected void onException(Throwable ex) {
                
            }

            protected void onExpire() {
                onException(new SocketTimeoutException());
            }

        };

        exchange.setScheme(HttpSchemes.HTTPS.equals(request.getScheme()) ? HttpSchemes.HTTPS_BUFFER
                : HttpSchemes.HTTP_BUFFER);
        exchange.setMethod(request.getMethod());
        exchange.setURL(url.toString());
        exchange.setVersion(request.getProtocol());
        exchange.setRequestHeader("Host", _hostHeader);
         
        exchange.setRequestHeader("Via", request.getProtocol() + " " + host + " (" + getClass().getSimpleName() + ")");
        if (!xForwardedFor) {
            exchange.addRequestHeader("X-Forwarded-For", request.getRemoteAddr());
            exchange.addRequestHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto", scheme);
            exchange.addRequestHeader("X-Forwarded-Host", host);
            exchange.addRequestHeader("X-Forwarded-Server", request.getLocalName());
            exchange.addRequestHeader(HttpServer.PROXY_URI_HEADER, from.toString());
        }
```

What are the alternatives to all the methods for "exchange" object?

Comment: Actually, Upgrading from Jetty 8.1.x to 9.4.x is 5 major versions in difference. (Reminder: Jetty versioning since 1995 is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`).  That class has evolved tremendously over time, and dropped around Jetty 9.1.x.  Please edit your question and include what you need to do and we can answer with more clarity. (Also note, that `HttpExchange` was both a Server class and a Client class at one point, and your question doesn't indicate which one you want to use)

Comment: There's also hints of you managing a Proxy, which is best handled with the `ProxyServlet`, `AsyncProxyServlet`, or if you need to mess with the contents, the `AsyncMiddleManServlet`.  Just extend from one of those and make the tweaks you need.

Comment: Also, the `X-Forwarded-*` headers are deprecated and non-standard, please use the formal spec `Forwarded` header which is defined at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7239 (which Jetty supports as well)